# IOT platforms, which to choose for my specific need.

Tags: wso2, mule, esb, iot, jbossfuse

i have been looking in to different IOT esb and platforms but its hard to check them all and test them all, and for a company in the startup process its even harder.

I have a hardware device which will send very little data but important data once in a while, there will however be some devices out there.

What i want to accomplish is this

1. My device react to a condition and send a message to my choice of iot platform
2. the iot platform will have a user management so the event can be stored for this user, the user will get a email and/or sms about the event.
3. I would like a dashboard for myself to view whats going on and be able to see what device belong to what user and status of it.
4. I want to be able to have an app that will show data / eventview for the specific user that owns the device.
5. Everything will be read only, i dont have need to send data to the device, only collect.

My need is rather simple, but i will charge a one time fee for the hardware and have no subscription, all the "cloud" platforms are rather expensive as i can see and they scale bad with their pricing. if i could get one that charge a few cent per device a year i could live with that and include it to the hardware price but the one i find is really above this or charge a high yearly fee from the start.

I have been looking around and trying to understand the program, platform and services out there.

**Cloud:**

- **Xively** - Expensive and dont have a model that scales per device
- **Azure** - Expensive, their price model is hard to understand
- **AWS** - Cheap to begin with but then Expensive, their price model is
  hard to understand
- **Mulesoft** - Expensive for my needs.

**Local installation:** Free software, dont have everything included and/or pay for training.

- **WSO2** - This one is hard, it might be able to solve my issues, but they have an IOT server that will open for BETA soon so i dont know
  much about it.
- **Mule community edition** - Might solve my issues but seems to lack the usermanagement and dashboard i need?
- **FuseESB** Might solve my issues but seems to lack the usermanagement and dashboard i need?
- **Kaa** - i have a hard time to see where kaa fits in, im not a programmer by trade so i think this platform is to hard for me and i dont know
  if it supports my needs, so far little information about it.

Can anyone sheed a light where i should look and put my effort in, i just dont have the time to give them all a shoot, and i might have misunderstood some of the platforms.

i would also appreciate an explanation what module,carbon, connects i would need to check in to, to solve my needs for the different platforms.

Might also be so that i have missed some superb platforms?

BR
Dimi

Comment: Looking at your question, I am sure you would have spend time evaluating options. Just want to add one thing - Azure pricing estimation can be done through a pricing calculator, which should make it easier to understand: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/
And Azure supports all the services you mentioned - including your point 5 :)

Comment: Azure can really do what i want it to do but i must say i dont like the pricing model for neaither of Azure, IBM, amazon, google. It starts out pretty cheap but as soon you want something to happen it seems to shoot away in price. I rather go for a service where i can have a better controll on the the cost. But thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

For WSO2, sign up for the beta here: http://wso2.com/landing/wso2-iot-server-beta-program/

This page has lots of info on how you can use already released components of WSO2 stack for your scenario: http://wso2.com/landing/wso2-iot-server-beta-program/ - see the reference architecture and webinars on the Resources tab.

Comment: Hello, i have already signed up for the BETA so we will have to see what will happen :). Thank you for the respons.

Comment: Yeah, I very much look forward to it as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use reekoh.com(data collection capabiliteis) and mule(if you don't want to pay then use MULE CE)

You may have a customisation work.

Comment: Hello and thank you. Reekoh seems to be a interesting platform. but you say i should use Reekoh and Mule. As i can see it i should be able to use everything i want inside the reekoh platform? Any specific reason why i should use Reekoh and Mule?

Answer (score 0):

The [Watson IoT Plaform](http://www.ibm.com/internet-of-things/) is available in IBM's Bluemix cloud and allows up to 20 registered devices, and 100 MB of data exchanged free.
 [image]

More detailed [pricing](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?direct=classic/#/pricing/cloudOEPaneId=pricing&paneId=pricingSheet&orgGuid=3e6802aa-f682-48ae-9b5d-1859984f8157&spaceGuid=d0c8b1af-54bd-4b5b-92c7-0d93004f68c6) info is available.

[Real-time insights](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/iotrtinsights/index.html) alerting can be configured to help provide the device specific data for users.

Comment: Aye IBM can really do what i want it to do but i must say i dont like the pricing model for neaither of Azure, IBM, amazon, google. It starts out pretty cheap but as soon you want something to happen it seems to shoot away in price. I rather go for a service where i can have a better controll on the the cost. But thank you for your input.